# Auto Resizing banner to fit different screen resolutions?

Tags: html, blogger, blogspot

i have a blog

http://mountaintopchef.blogspot.com/

i want my header (banner) to Auto Resize to fit different screen resolutions. i think its called a fluid layout when it adjusts to all screen sizes. i found some codes online but none match my themes code. Its ok if it cant fill the screen till the horizontal ends but at least it will be center.

my blogs full html
http://codeshare.io/pltQg

thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly used Google Chrome Inspect Element to find the banner code and all i did was change

```
<img alt="Mountain Top Chef" height="252px; " id="Header1_headerimg" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5nGgddhpZl4/VedKBQbgsCI/AAAAAAAAAlQ/40XzdyCllRo/s1600-r/mountain-top-chef-banner%2B.jpg" style="display: block" width="100%; ">
```

to

```
<img alt="Mountain Top Chef" height="252px; " id="Header1_headerimg" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5nGgddhpZl4/VedKBQbgsCI/AAAAAAAAAlQ/40XzdyCllRo/s1600-r/mountain-top-chef-banner%2B.jpg" style="display: block" width="1264px; ">
```

or easier to see

```
width="1264px;
```

to

```
width="100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), and drop a container-fluid class on your banner.

In code, you would include bootstrap in yourh head through CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And you would add this to your banner img:

```
class="container-fluid"
```

Ending up with:

```
<img alt="Mountain Top Chef" height="252px; " id="Header1_headerimg" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5nGgddhpZl4/VedKBQbgsCI/AAAAAAAAAlQ/40XzdyCllRo/s1600-r/mountain-top-chef-banner%2B.jpg" style="display: block" width="1264px; " class="container-fluid">
```

(I got the code directly from your page)

Bootstrap [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp).